# node - Module Error from ./eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js): require() of ES Module \prettier\index.mjs not supported ( NODE VERSION v16.20.1)

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-scripts

I have bought an online soup restaurant menu with online ordering system :
**with node.js verion 16.20.1
and  the prettier
"prettier": "^3.0.1",
"prettier-eslint": "^9.0.1",
"prettier-stylelint": "^0.4.2"
and the webpack: 4.46.0**
I made a lot of configuration upgrading the packages - it failed to run npm run-script build successfully with this error:

```
> soup-html@1.0.0 build
> webpack --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js

Hash: 7ea76108d2c2528a690f
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 45540ms
Built at: 08/08/2023 9:03:27 PM
 11 assets
Entrypoint core = ../css/core.css core.js
 [4] ./src/js/modules/cookies.js 1.26 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]        
 [7] ./src/js/modules/custom-control.js 446 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
 [9] ./src/js/modules/back-to-top.js 592 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]   
[10] ./src/js/modules/cart.js 13.8 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
[11] ./src/js/modules/navigation.js 2.76 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]     
[12] ./src/js/modules/sticky.js 950 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[15] ./src/js/modules/page-transition.js 1.12 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
[16] ./src/js/modules/background.js 805 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[17] ./src/js/modules/carousel.js 2.41 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
[18] ./src/js/modules/collapse.js 609 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[19] ./src/js/modules/components.js 528 bytes {0} [built] [1 error]
[20] ./src/js/modules/forms.js 3.23 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
[21] ./src/js/modules/google-map.js 1.24 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
[29] multi ./src/js/core.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
[30] ./src/js/core.js 2.38 KiB {0} [built] [1 error]
    + 53 hidden modules

ERROR in ./src/js/core.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
require() of ES Module D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\prettier\index.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\prettier\index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Occurred while linting D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\src\js\core.js:12
 @ multi ./src/js/core.js core[0]

ERROR in ./src/js/globals.js
Module Error (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
require() of ES Module D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\prettier\index.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\prettier\index.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
Occurred while linting D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\src\js\globals.js:1
 @ ./src/js/modules/cart.js 8:0-59 155:374-382 182:6-18 187:6-18 214:6-11 257:498-506 275:225-233
 @ ./src/js/core.js
 @ multi ./src/js/core.js
```

[npm run-script build output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXGit.jpg) 
[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1q2n.jpg)

**I have upgrade the node js version and the packages nothing worked out**

and I try also to modify the: cjs.js
from

```
const loader = require('./index');

module.exports = loader.default;
```

to :

```
import loader from './index';

export default loader;
```

I got this error:

```
> soup-html@1.0.0 build
> webpack --config build/webpack.prod.conf.js

Hash: d90a6ec28b96c9967a03
Version: webpack 4.46.0
Time: 3515ms
Built at: 08/08/2023 9:24:00 PM
 1 asset
Entrypoint core = core.js
[0] multi ./src/js/core.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
[1] ./src/js/core.js 3.2 KiB {0} [not cacheable] [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/js/core.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js):
D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\eslint-loader\dist\cjs.js:3
import loader from './index';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at new Script (node:vm:100:7)
    at NativeCompileCache._moduleCompile (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:240:18)
    at Module._compile (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:184:36)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)
    at require (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at loadLoader (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:18:17)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:165:10)
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:176:18      
    at loadLoader (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\loadLoader.js:47:3)
    at iteratePitchingLoaders (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:169:2)
    at runLoaders (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\loader-runner\lib\LoaderRunner.js:365:2)
    at NormalModule.doBuild (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:295:3)
    at NormalModule.build (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModule.js:446:15)
    at Compilation.buildModule (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:739:10)
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:981:14
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:409:6      
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:155:13     
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at AsyncSeriesWaterfallHook.lazyCompileHook (D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:138:29     
    at D:\soup_restaurant_with_online_ordering_system\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:346:9      
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11)
 @ multi ./src/js/core.js core[0]
```

Comment: It was a problem with my node version problem fixed